# Can an I2C switch control multiple I2C switches?

Tags: microcontroller, switches, i2c

I was wondering if I am able to treat an I2C switch simply as another I2C device and use 1 switch to control more switches downstream. This picture below shows what I am trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. But they do not need to be in different addresses, unless you want to select all of them simultaneously with the first mux, but then they can be all connected to the MCU directly without the first mux.

Comment: If you aren't using I2C hardware ports and you have enough of those ports. If your bit-banging it doesn't matter

Comment: A great solution but you do need to be careful with addressing. The TCA9548 has only have 3 unique addresses to play with. You use the first on the level 1 device ….at level two you only have two unique TCA9548 addresses left, so you'd allocate those to all the Level 2 TCA9548. At Level 3 (should you go that far) you'd use the third address.

Comment: It has 3 address pins, therefore 8 addresses.